# LINQ To SQL - Get SQL that has been run

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I am working on a system that uses LINQ to SQL to call a SPROC.

Is there a way of getting the SQL that **ExecuteMethodCall** has executed

**CLARIFICATION** the reason I want the SQL is to log the SQL to file at the C# level.

Comment: Do you want to detect the execution for debugging, or at runtime for logic purposes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386961%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property:

```
// Attach a TextWriter, e.g. Console.Out
db.Log = File.CreateText(@"sql.log");

IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

foreach(var custObj in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(custObj.CustomerID);
}
```

Comment: I stand corrected. Was going off of memory from the Beta 4 years ago. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to capture the SQL statements being executed against your SQL Server

Comment: Thanks, the reason I want the SQL is to log the SQL to file at the C# level so profiler not much use for me here.